# Kartik Yii2 Number - Getting value from extension

Tags: javascript, yii2

I am using [Kartik Yii2 Number](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-number) and I have problem with getting value using this extension..

I need to use `onkeypress` or `onkeyup` or `onkeydown` to call javascript function, but this extension just allow me using `onchange` to call javascript function..

this is my form code :

```
<?= $form->field($target, "[$index]anggaran")->widget(NumberControl::classname(), [
    'maskedInputOptions' => [
        'prefix' => 'Rp. ',
        'groupSeparator' => '.',
        'radixPoint' => ',',
        'allowMinus' => false,
        'digits' => 1000,
    ],
    'options' => ['onkeypress' => 'kalkulasiAnggaran()'],
    'displayOptions' => ['class' => 'form-control kv-monospace'],
])->label(false) ?>
```

and this is my javascript function :

```
function kalkulasiAnggaran()
{
    var total_anggaran = 0;
    total_anggaran = parseFloat($("#anggaran").val());

    console.log(total_anggaran.toFixed(2));
}
```

is there anything I can do to solve this problem??..

Comment: It is unclear what the problem is. It sounds like you want to react to value changes but do not want to use `onchange`?

Comment: @RaulSauco, yes, I can't use `onchange`, thats why I need `onkeypress`, `onkeyup`, or `onkeydown` for this particular form..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add your own JavaScript to handle changes, the plugin simply hides the actual input and replaces it with a *display* input that has the same Id followed by `-disp`.

For example, if your input was `mymodel-attr` the generated *display* input would be:

```html
<input type="text" 
  id="mymodel-attr-disp" 
  class="form-control kv-monospace" 
  name="expense-unit_price-disp" 
  value="250.00" 
  style="text-align: right;"
>
```

Write some JS to handle update events and add it to the page, for example, if you wanted to add it directly to the view file:

```php
<?php
$js = <<<'JS'
$(document).ready(function () {
  const $input = $('#mymodel-attr-disp');
  $input.keydown(function () {
      const newValue = $(this).val();
      console.log(`(jquery keydown event) I changed to ${newValue}`);
    });
  $input.keyup(function () {
      const newValue = $(this).val();
      console.log(`(jquery keyup event) I changed to ${newValue}`);
    });
  $input.on('input', function () {
      const newValue = $(this).val();
      console.log(`(jquery input event) I changed to ${newValue}`);
    });
});
JS;
$this->registerJs($js);
```

##### Update: using a dynamically generated ID

Instead of using [nowdoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) like on the original example, update the code to use [heredoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc), then use your PHP variable's value in your JS:

```php
<?php
$inputId = 'model-attribute';
$js = <<<JS
$(document).ready(function () {
  const input = $('#$inputId-disp');
  input.keydown(function () {
      const newValue = $(this).val();
      console.log('(jquery keydown event) I changed to ' + newValue);
    });
  input.keyup(function () {
      const newValue = $(this).val();
      console.log('(jquery keyup event) I changed to ' + newValue);
    });
  input.on('input', function () {
      const newValue = $(this).val();
      console.log('(jquery input event) I changed to ' + newValue);
    });
});
JS;
$this->registerJs($js);
```

Note that the above code is PHP, the JS is just a string in your PHP code, so you do get a lot of flexibility with what you do with it, at the cost of sending the code on each request.

You have a few ways to optimize this, for example:

1. Use the `options` attribute on the *widget* to assign an ID: `'options' => ['id' => 'my-input-id']` then move all your JS to a file and load it using Yii's assets.
2. Only output the dynamic ID on the view file, make that JS depend on the file that has the logic that handles the `input` event.

You can use the following snippet to test what actions triggers different events on the input:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const $input = $('#mymodel-attr-disp');
  $input.keydown(function() {
    const newValue = $(this).val();
    console.log(`(jquery keydown event) I changed to ${newValue}`);
  });
  $input.keyup(function() {
    const newValue = $(this).val();
    console.log(`(jquery keyup event) I changed to ${newValue}`);
  });
  $input.on('input', function() {
    const newValue = $(this).val();
    console.log(`(jquery input event) I changed to ${newValue}`);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="mymodel-attr-disp" class="form-control kv-monospace" name="expense-unit_price-disp" value="250.00" style="text-align: right;">
```

**input** seems to be what you are looking for, i.e. it will handle *paste* events, but won't trigger when only `ctrl` is pressed, but you can use the different event handlers above to test and see which behavior is the one that better fits your needs, then remove the ones you don't need.

Comment: hi @RaulSauco, this solution is great, but the id is dynamic, thats why I can't use fixed variable like this `const $input = $('#mymodel-attr-disp');`, instead using fixed variable, I use this to call JS/JQuery function `'onkeypress' => 'kalkulasiAnggaran()'` which is unfortunately not working..

Comment: @biladina you are generating the JS in your view, using a dynamically generated ID is not a problem, just use some PHP string type that parses variables, I added an example with heredoc.

Comment: You can also use the `options` attribute on the widget to assign an ID, then query the visible input by adding `-disp` to that ID.

Answer (score 0):

after more digging on [Kartik Yii2 Number](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-number) code, I realize that the `extension` already using all keyboard event (`keyup`, `keydown`, `keypress`) to parse all input, so user can't directly use the keyboard event to get value, all event left that can be use in the `extension` is `change` event, but we can initiate standalone JavaScript to use keyboard event (`keyup`, `keydown`, `keypress`)..

as I mention before, I use `form` with dynamic ID, because the `form` is inside `foreach` looping, instead of catch dynamic ID as [@RaulSauco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2557030/raul-sauco) suggest, I cast a `class` to all looping `form` with same `class` name and check the `form` that contain exact `class` in JavaScript, and I need use `regex` to parse all value from the `form` because it contains `prefix`, `suffix`, and all `separator` from the `extension`..

this is all my code..

controller :

```
$count = 6;
for($i = 1; $i < $count; $i++)
{
    $model[] = new \common\models\Total();
}

return $this->render('form', [
    'model' => $model,
    'count' => $count,
]);
```

form :

```
$this->registerJs("
$(document).ready(function() {
    function kalkulasiAnggaran()
    {
        var count = $count;
        var total_anggaran = 0;

        for(i=0; i<count; i++)
        {
            total_anggaran += parseFloat($('#'+i+'_target_rp-disp').val().replace(/[^0-9,]/g, '').replace(/,/g, '.') );
        }

        console.log(total_anggaran.toFixed(2));
    }

    $('.target_rp').keyup(function() {
        kalkulasiAnggaran();
    });

    kalkulasiAnggaran();
});
");

<?php foreach($model as $index => $target) { ?>
    <?= $form->field($target, "[$index]target_rp")->widget(NumberControl::classname(), [
        'maskedInputOptions' => [
            'prefix' => 'Rp. ',
            'groupSeparator' => '.',
            'radixPoint' => ',',
            'allowMinus' => false,
            'digits' => 1000,
        ],
        'options' => ['value' => $target->isNewRecord ? '0' : $target->target_rp],
        'displayOptions' => ['id' => $index.'_target_rp-disp', 'class' => 'form-control kv-monospace target_rp'],
    ])->label(false) ?>
<?php } ?>
```

thats it, I able to use `keyup` event to get direct value when user input..

this is not the ideal approach, because I had to catch all user input and parse it to actual number, but it works..

if you guys have any simple or quick approach, post your answer..